# Is it possible to specify Exchange version when sending email with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, email, version, exchange-server

I am trying to send an email via Exchange using PowerShell. Is it possible to specify what version of Exchange to use? I don't know if Send-MailMessage is the correct function to use either.

The server requires username and password, and should use Exchange2007_SP1.

Running the code below returns "Send-MailMessage: Service Not Available. Closing Channel. Server response 4.3.2 Service Not Available".

So it seems that the server gets this, but rejects it.

The secured server that this runs on, has no direct internet connection, but can reach the Exchange server. Hence, I cannot download and install addons to PowerShell, if that is required.

Any ideas out there? Am I attacking this from the wrong angle?

````
$sendMailParams = @{
    From = 'sender@somemailaccount.com' 
    To = 'johndoe@someexchangeserver.com'
    Subject = 'some subject here'
    Body = 'some body here'
    SMTPServer = 'exchange.server.com'
    UseSsl = $true
    Credential = $mailCred
}

Send-MailMessage @sendMailParams```
````

Comment: If the server listening for SMTP submissions at `exchange.server.com` is an Exchange 2007 server then that's what it'll use. There's no mechanism in SMTP itself for indicating "please route this via a specific version of a specific mail server"

Comment: If you’re using SSL you probably want to specify the port as well. Exchange version shouldn’t matter at all.

Comment: It does work when connecting to Exchange from UiPath, but that application has a function of its own for this, and it lets you specify what Exchange version to use. Seems like PowerShell doesn't...

Comment: Could it be that PowerShell isn't an accepted application on the Exchange server?

Comment: @Tom-IngeNilsen, try specifying the default SSL port with `-Port 465` or remove the `-UseSSL` line. I know exchange 2007 doesn't support TLS1.1/1.2 either for SMTP, so if you happen to have older versions disabled in powershell, then that could cause issues as well (probably a different error though).

Comment: Also, Exchange 2007 went end of life more than 4 years ago (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/exchange-2007-end-of-support?view=o365-worldwide)  you really shouldn't have this machine connected to a network.

Comment: I'll try the port tip and see if that helps. I know Exchange 2007 is old, this is in a secure off-internet citrix environment, so no worries. It routes out through newer exchange servers, but they cannot be reached directly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this not working in the first place is due to PowerShell policies on the terminal servers. For security reasons, sending mail from PowerShell has been disabled, since you can mail to anyone, from anyone. When you log on to the system in the morning, you get a random terminal server. If I'd been logged on to the same one all the time, it might have been an option to enable it on that specific terminal server. But as it is, it is too open to enable it on all servers, so that's why it is restricted.

If things change in the future, it might be an option to do this.

I know this isn't a direct answer to the question, but it is no longer relevant for me. IT says it isn't necessary to specify Exchange version when sending through PowerShell.

Thanks for all your inputs, folks. You are the best.